# Transition from multi layer to single layer

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, transition, scene, multi-layer

I've got problem with my code. I make a transition from a single layer to a multi layer and then rotate the device.
After that, i replace the multi layer back to a single layer, again. Everything works as expected until I rotate the device again, then...

Taaraaaa..
Application stop running..
Is there someone who can help me??
for code:
SINGLE LAYER to MLUTI LAYER

```
- (void)goToGamePlayScene:(id)sender {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[[[MultiLayerScene alloc] initWithGameBoardName:@"coba2"] autorelease]];
```

}

MULTI LAYER to SINGLE LAYER
note:The following code is the code of the class being the son of a multi-layer class

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[HomeScene node]];
```